# INSERT and DELETE in single operation (moving from one table to other)

Tags: mysql, insert, transaction, delete, copy

Stemming from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143383/user-variable-in-nested-subquery-not-getting-picked-up-in-complex-sort-of-2-ta), I am going to use that complex sort's results to decide which rows' data to move from one table to another. Though I have not yet tried it, I think there should be no problem to do the "copy" part via a:

```
INSERT * FROM (...)
```

Using my results from that `SELECT` inside the parentheses.

However, if I then user the same query to try to `SELECT` the same results in order to do a `DELETE FROM`, the results will no longer include those same rows. So, I need some way to store at least the primary keys (and origin table, since we are talking about 2 origin tables and one destination table) in order to `DELETE` the correct row from the correct table.

From what I have read and understood, it's not possible to do in a single query, and in any case would require a transaction (which I need to lookup how to correctly do).

So my first approach would be to do the `INSERT` copy first, and then maybe delete form the two tables any rows containing primary keys appearing in my destination table. It seems a little inefficient since that table would be *much* larger than the two origin tables, and I figure that from the derived table I got from my subquery, it would be much much more efficient to use the info located there. So, any clues as to how I could best go about this?

Comment: Could you expand on this with some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: @Vérace, you mean copy the sample data from the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those curious, this is how I solved it, thanks to @evanSteinbrenner's tip:

```
LOCK TABLES
    main WRITE,
    main as t WRITE,
    main as t_in WRITE,
    main as df WRITE,
    main_date WRITE,
    main_date as d WRITE,
    main_date as d2 WRITE,
    main_date as dx WRITE,
    main_weekday WRITE,
    main_weekday as w WRITE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stacks_tmp AS ( $sql_stacks_ready );
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stacks_tmp ORDER BY date;
INSERT INTO main (id, title, added_on, date) SELECT  id, title, added_on, date FROM  stacks_tmp;
DELETE FROM main_date WHERE  (id) IN (SELECT id FROM   stacks_tmp WHERE from_table = 'date') ;
DELETE FROM main_weekday WHERE  (id) IN (SELECT id FROM   stacks_tmp WHERE from_table = 'weekday') ;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This is just simplified out from the original `perl/dbi` code, which does some logic to check each statement for failure. I do not have it using transactions yet, since I still have yet to learn that. The `$sql_stacks_ready` variable contains my (semi) complex query that creates the ordered stack (and hence the need for all those aliases in the `LOCK TABLES`). The column `from_table` is set by the stack building query, and is set to whatever the originating table was.

Answer (score 2):

Insert everything into a temp table first. Then your insert and delete are simply everything from the temp table rather than your complicated query. This solves your problem of how to do both halves and is probably going to perform better than running your complicated query multiple times.

I do more MS-SQL than My-SQL so I'll link to another answer on Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table

On MS-SQL it is simply

```
  SELECT .... into #MyTempTable FROM ... WHERE..
```

Comment: Interesting! My knowledge is still very limited, can you edit to add an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Evan OP question is tagged with MySQL, not with SQL Server. Beside using temp table with SQL Server will create tempdb IOs.

Comment: Thanks to this answer though, I quite quickly whipped up a solution using temp tables that solves all my problems.. though not in a single operation, of course.

Comment: An equivalent for MySQL would probably be `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tablename AS SELECT ...`.

Comment: @Evan, I have posted my solution which I came to thanks to your tip. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger which insert into `table2` what has been removed from `table1`.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id int, name varchar(10), level int);
INSERT INTO table1(id, name, level) VALUES
  (0, 'a', 0)
  , (1, 'b', 1)
  , (2, 'c', 0)
  , (3, 'd', 2)
  , (4, 'e', 1)
  , (4, 'f', 0);

CREATE TABLE table2(id int, name varchar(10), level int);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER table1_after_delete
    AFTER DELETE
    ON table1 FOR EACH ROW        
    trig: BEGIN
    IF (@TRIGGER_AFTER_DELETE_ENABLE = FALSE)
    THEN
        LEAVE trig;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO table2
    ( 
        id
        , name
        , level
    )
    VALUES
    ( 
        OLD.id
        , OLD.name
        , OLD.level 
    );
END; //

DELIMITER ;

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE level = 1;
SET @TRIGGER_AFTER_DELETE_ENABLE = FALSE;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE level = 2;
```

This sample deletes everything in `table1` where `level=1` and then where `level=2`. It moves it to `table2` only when `@TRIGGER_AFTER_DELETE_ENABLE <> FALSE`. See sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc53aa/1).

Therefore:

- rows with 1 are inserted into table2 (variable is not set yet)
- rows with 2 are not inserted into table2 (variable set to FALSE)

#### Output from table1:

```
d   name    level
0   a       0
2   c       0
4   f       0
```

#### Output from table2:

```
id  name    level
1   b       1
4   e       1
```

Row with `level=2` is not here anymore (See sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc53aa/1)).

You basically choose like this:

- `@TRIGGER_AFTER_DELETE_ENABLE = FALSE` before the delete statement => delete and copy data
- `@TRIGGER_AFTER_DELETE_ENABLE <> FALSE` => only delete data

#### SQL Server

Although the question is not about this RDBMS, with SQL Server I would rather use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
DELETE FROM t
OUTPUT deleted.id, deleted.name, deleted.level INTO table2
FROM table1 t
WHERE level > 0;
```

It simply inserts somewhere else the output of what has just been deleted. No temp table is needed and IO will be limited on `tempdb`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however for my use case this isn't so great, since if I wanted to delete a row that I didn't want going into my main table, this would require some sort of workaround.

Comment: see update. you only need to set a variable and choose between delete/move or simply delete